# Having trouble reading mutiple text files from a folder. filenotfoundexception

Tags: java, hashmap

I have no problem getting it to run but it crashes when I hit the "Find Ranking" button. I've tried running it in BlueJ and NetBeans, both have the same issues. I get the following error:

```
 java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Marque/Desktop/Years (Is a directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
    at Main.readFile(Main.java:128)
    at Main$1.actionPerformed(Main.java:94)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Below is my code.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main {
   Map<String,String> fileMap;

   JFrame f;
   JPanel yearPanel;
   JLabel yearLabel;
   JComboBox yearBox;
   JPanel genderPanel;
   JLabel genderLabel;
   JComboBox genderBox;
   JPanel namePanel;
   JLabel nameLabel;
   JTextField tf1;
   JPanel textPanel;
   JTextField textField;
   Main(){
       fileMap = new HashMap<String,String>();

       fileMap.put("2006", "/Users/Marque/Desktop/Years/2006.txt");
       fileMap.put("2007", "/Users/Marque/Desktop/Years/2007.txt");
       fileMap.put("2008", "/Users/Marque/Desktop/Years/2008.txt");
       fileMap.put("2009", "/Users/Marque/Desktop/Years/2009.txt");
       fileMap.put("2010", "/Users/Marque/Desktop/Years/2010.txt");

       String years[]={"2006","2007","2008","2009","2010"};
       String genders[]={"MALE","FEMALE"};
       f=new JFrame("Baby Name Popularity");

       yearPanel= new JPanel();
       yearLabel =new JLabel("Year");
       yearPanel.add(yearLabel);
       yearBox=new JComboBox<String>(years);
       yearPanel.add(yearBox);
       yearPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
       f.add(yearPanel);

       genderPanel= new JPanel();
       genderLabel =new JLabel("Gender");
       genderPanel.add(genderLabel);
       genderBox=new JComboBox<String>(genders);
       genderPanel.add(genderBox);
       genderPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
       f.add(genderPanel);

       namePanel= new JPanel();
       nameLabel =new JLabel("NAME");
       namePanel.add(nameLabel);
       tf1 = new JTextField();
       namePanel.add(tf1);
       namePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
       f.add(namePanel);

       JPanel buttonPanel= new JPanel();
       buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
       JButton jb =new JButton("Find Ranking");

       buttonPanel.add(jb,0);

       f.add(buttonPanel);


       textPanel= new JPanel();
       textField = new JTextField();
       textPanel.add(textField);
       textPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
       f.add(textPanel);

       jb.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
               String year = (String)yearBox.getSelectedItem();
               String gender =(String)genderBox.getSelectedItem();
               String name =(String)tf1.getText();
               readFile("Years");
           }
       });

       f.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2,10,20));
       f.setSize(400,500);
       f.setVisible(true);  

   }

   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       new Main();
   }

   public void readFile(String FILENAME){

       if(fileMap.containsKey(FILENAME))
           FILENAME = fileMap.get("/Users/Marque/Desktop/Years");

       BufferedReader br = null;
       FileReader fr = null;

       try {

           fr = new FileReader("/Users/Marque/Desktop/Years");
           br = new BufferedReader(fr);

           String sCurrentLine;

           br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILENAME));
           boolean found =false;
           String name = (String)tf1.getText().trim();
           while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
               sCurrentLine=sCurrentLine.replaceAll("\\s+"," ");
               for(int i=0;i<sCurrentLine.split(" ").length;i++)
               {
                   String s=sCurrentLine.split(" ")[i];
                   if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(name)){
                       found=true;
                       textField.setText(""+s+" was #"+sCurrentLine.split(" ")[i+1]+" in "+yearBox.getSelectedItem()+"!");
                   }
               }
               if(!found)
               {
                   textField.setText("NAME NOT FOUND");
               }
           }

       } catch (IOException e) {

           e.printStackTrace();

       } finally {

           try {

               if (br != null)
                   br.close();

               if (fr != null)
                   fr.close();

           } catch (IOException ex) {

               ex.printStackTrace();

           }

       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

refer to this:

[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html](http://FileReader%20Class)

This class states that it accepts 3 types of parameter input:

```
FileReader(File file);
FileReader(FileDescriptor fd);
FileReader(String fileName);
```

Looks like you're passing a directory while it explicitly states that you need to pass a File or a file location path.